# ¿Por qué Git no reconoce mi contraseña? (Permission denied)

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Cuando ejecuto `git pull` me pide la contraseña, la ingreso pero no la reconoce. El problema radica en que no me pide la contraseña de mi usuario o mi clave pública, me pide el usuario git por defecto, o al menos pienso eso.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ git pull origin2 release_2.0
git@190.156.238.167's password: *********
Permisson denied, please try again.
git@190.156.238.167's password: *********
Permisson denied, please try again.
```

Se supone que no debe decir `git@190.156.238.167's` sino mi llave o mi nombre de usuario.

Comment: Parece que estuvieras trabajando con el usuario `git` por alguna razón. ¿No será que has ejecutado `su - git` antes o que te logueas con dicho usuario por alguna circunstancia? ¿Has intentado realizar los mismos pasos desde un nuevo terminal?

Comment: No la verdad ya lo intente y me sigue pidiendo el password del usuario git, tienes alguna otra idea por la que puede suceder esto. Gracias

Comment: Como te conectas al servidor x, con https o ssh?

Comment: Hola por favor especifica si estas intentando autenticar por `https` o `ssh` en el primer caso deberías revisar la contraseña en el servidor, en el segundo solo hace falta subir la clave publica. El servidor contra el que intentas autenticar es publico o uno privado, lo mismo para el repositorio puede que no tengas permisos para subir cambios. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te reconoce la contrasena porque tienes que crear un ssh key de nuevo y anadirlo de nuevamente en tu repositorio
Por ejemplo:
Git global setup
git config --global user.name "Eduardo Herrera" 
git config --global user.email "e.herrera@ifarhu.gob.pa"
create a new ssh key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "e.herrera@ifarhu.gob.pa"

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
este ultimo te mostrara la llave y tienes que agregarlo en el repositorio.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

```
git remote set-url origin git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:<nombre-de-proyecto>.git
```

¿Estás seguro que debes usar `origin2`?

Sólo por curiosidad, ¿podrías mostrar el resultado del comando `git remote -v`?